# python modules with RubyPython

Tags: python, ruby

I've just started working with RubyPython, and though the documentation says you can load modules, it doesn't have any examples or directions to do that.

I've got Python NLTK installed on my machine (Ubuntu if it matters), and can import the module when running Python from the command line.

However, I'm under the impression that the RubyPython gem installs another version of Python which the gem interacts with from Ruby (though I could be wrong).

Is there a different folder I need to install NLTK to, or something else I need to do to access NLTK from Ruby through RubyPython?

I have confirmed that RubyPython itself is loading into Rails code properly.

The code I'm running is just

```
        RubyPython.start
        import nltk
        RubyPython.stop
```

and I get

```
undefined local variable or method `nltk'
```

I can't create the tag RubyPython which is why this article isn't tagged as such.

Comment: I don't know this RubyPython, but that's not the message from an `ImportError`. I think you should use different syntax.

Comment: @larsmans - you should put that as an answer and I'll accept it. I needed to write it as RubyPython.import("nltk").. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
RubyPython.start
nltk = RubyPython.import("nltk")
RubyPython.stop
```

also you can specify which Python interpreter you want to use by doing:

```
RubyPython.start(:python_exe => "python2.7") # Can also be a full path
```

Comment: thanks @free-dom, is there anywhere that you've seen documented or examples of using nltk with RubyPython? I haven't come up with anything

Comment: I haven't seen much on nltk specifically however there is no reason that I can think of that it wouldn't behave well with RubyPython. You'll just need to remember to "rubify" any strings that come back from python methods you invoke and it should all work well. The best examples of using RubyPython are here: http://rubypython.rubyforge.org/ but you've probably  already seen that by now.